# Probability that seven concerts get distributed to every unique day of a week using Markov chains?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, soft-question, markov-chains

I saw a question some hour ago which sadly got closed because it was duplicate so I did not have the time to figure out an answer.

Can we use Markov chains to calculate the probability that if having 7 concerts during one week and every concert is equally probable to happen any day, what is the probability that they all end up on all the 7 different days?

Something along the lines of:

1. Select one day for the first concert. This succeeds in 100% of the cases, because every day is free.
2. Select one day for second concert. (Given that 1 succeeded), this succeeds with rate 6/7, since there is only one day which yet is taken.
3. Select one day for third concert. (Given that 2 succeeded), this succeeds with rate 5/7, since there are only two out of seven days which are yet taken.
4. ...

So every success above takes us to one new state and every failure takes us to some failure state which we can't get out of.

Is this a valid approach to solve this problem or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, though I would not bother calling this a markov chain.  I suppose if you really want to, you could phrase it as such.  Instead, I would simply call this a sequence of events and use the multiplication principle for probability to describe the resulting calculation... something taught *far* earlier in ones education.  Yes $\frac{7!}{7^7}$ is the correct probability here.

Comment: Yes that is the whole point. To not use the easiest way just because it is possible, but to use a slightly more advanced one to introduce a more powerful tool in problem solving. We don't get much better by using the easiest ways all the time, do we?

Comment: Given that the calculations performed are identical and the only difference between them is the flavor of what each of the fractions represent, I do not see the point personally.  It seems to unnecessarily complicate the explanation.  That doesn't make it wrong per se, but certainly unnecessary.

Comment: Learning new tools for problem solving is *unnecessary*? Ehm, okay.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that learning new tools for problem solving or learning about markov chains is not useful.  I'm just saying that this problem example is a bad one to introduce the concept with.  If I want to get the area of a rectangle of side-lengths $1$ and $2$, I don't need to mention measure theory or integration.  The type of student who is usually asked a problem of the type "find the area of a rectangle of side lengths $1$ and $2$" will not be ready for those topics yet.  Similarly, a student asked for the probability in your post may not yet be ready for markov chains.

Comment: If you wish to introduce markov chains to someone, I would do so with a problem that by using markov chains makes the calculations easier than a more basic approach could manage, one that showcases the benefits of using them.  Regardless, this is getting into the topic of pedagogy and is highly subjective.  These are just my opinions on the matter.

Comment: That is true, but the others readers and people writing answers may be ready for it.